# What are the advantages of NRF24L01 when compared to LORA module

Tags: networking, communication, lora

i am designing an Iot project. In that project i want to transfer small bytes of information from one place to another place which is located more than 2kms away from previous location. therefore distance and also durability and ability to cross hard objects like trees are important parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The main factor in your application is the range, durability, and ability so according to it, you should use the LoRaWAN network. Because it's range is an urban environment with an outdoor gateway is about 2-3km wide coverage and in a rural area more than 5km

The range of NRF24l01 max 100 meters that too in open space and with the lowest baud rate. If you want to use NRF24L01 you have to buy and connect it to a PA and an LNA like [this](https://probots.co.in/nrf24l01-pa-lna-long-range-antenna-wireless-transceiver-module.html).

There are different LoRa Modules available in the market and they work on different frequencies but have large area network coverage.

Below are the links to the datasheet of some LoRa modules and NRF24L01:

[SX1276/77/78/79 - 137 MHz to 1020 MHz Low Power Long Range Transceiver](https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/SX1278%20Lora%20Datasheet.pdf)

[RN2903 Low-Power Long Range LoRa® Technology Transceiver Module](https://lora-alliance.org/sites/default/files/showcase-documents/rn2903-lora-module-datasheet.pdf)

[NRF24L01](https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/nRF24L01%20Datasheet.pdf)

Please read the datasheet and compare it. Learn to read the datasheet of modules as it will help you a lot in the future deciding for the components.

Comment: thanks a lot for you answer actually i want to use another technology except lora while searching in the web i saw a video where they transfer data between two 30km distanced locations are there any technology that i can use rather than lora

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XRp7pkZgPM

Comment: As I said you have to use an external antenna to increase the range of the NRF24L01. That guy in the video is using one external antenna for the NRF24L01. There are other technologies please see these [link1](https://www.iotforall.com/iot-connectivity-comparison-lora-sigfox-rpma-lpwan-technologies/),[link2](https://www.link-labs.com/blog/nb-iot-vs-lora-vs-sigfox). I think the alternative to LoRa is using GSM Module (As I have not used others so can't say about them). You can transfer your data to the cloud and fetch that data on the other end without any issues.